# mui DataGrid scroll bar doesn't work on columnHeader

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I scroll the scroll bar left/right only the rows in the body move, but the header row stays as it is.

**screenshot**: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWnQW.png)

code:

```
<DataGrid
  className={classes.root}
  components={{
    Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
    NoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
    LoadingOverlay: CustomLoadingOverlay,
  }}
  loading={data.length === 0}
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  autoHeight
  hideFooter
  disableSelectionOnClick
  localeText={customLocaleText}
  disableColumnMenu 
/>
```

This is my custom style for the DataGrid

```
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();
export const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme) => ({
    root: {
      border: 0,
      
      "& .MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator": {
        display: "none",
      },
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader, .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
        borderRight: "1px solid #f0f0f0",
        backgroundColor: "#e6e9ef",
      },
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer, .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
        borderBottom: "1px solid #f0f0f0",
        backgroundColor: "#f4f4f5",
      },
      "& .MuiDataGrid-cell--editable": {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },
      "& .Mui-error": {
        backgroundColor: "#ffe6e6",
        color: "#ff4343",
      },
    },
  }),
  { defaultTheme }
);
```

Material-UI Data Grid demo - https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version

Answer (score 4):

I have the same exact problem. It took me hours of struggling to figure it out.

This is actually **a bug on Material-UI side**. The problem occurs when you use the DataGrid component in a **right-to-left** layout or container.

The MUI examples are all in English which is LTR, and that's why it works fine on the documentation.
However, *for RTL languages such as Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc this problem arises*.

I have created an issue for the corresponding repo on GitHub.
Also I created this [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-mountain-ldisj) which shows the problem. If you change the **dir** attribute of the container div to '**ltr**' the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, but you can set `direction: ltr` to `MuiDataGrid-root` div, and give `transform: rotateY(180deg)` style to the `MuiDataGrid-root` class, and then again add `transform: rotateY(180deg)` to the internal elements (title, content, etc.) classes for reverse the opposite!

like this:

```
.MuiDataGrid-root.MuiDataGrid-root--densityStandard {
  direction: ltr !important;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

  .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text.MuiButton-textPrimary {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    color: #141414 !important;
  }

  .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .MuiDataGrid-cellContent {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .MuiDataGrid-footerContainer {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .MuiButton-startIcon.MuiButton-iconSizeSmall {
    margin-left: -2px !important;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know this is a bug in `Right To Left` direction component on Material-UI side, i tried resolve it by this trick.

> I need to say that i cant use `useRef`, cause have not access to that class of `MUI Datagrid` that named `MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller`

1. Set `ltr` direction to parent of `Datagrid`
2. Reverse the order of the columns
3. install jquery by  `npm i jquery`
4. import jquery in grid page by `import $ from 'jquery'`
5. Write the `useEffect` below

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let myDivElement = $('.MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller');
      myDivElement.scrollLeft(myDivElement.width());
    }, 100);
  }, []);
```